# Netlify not able to serve static html page, however it opens up on localhost

Tags: html, node.js, post, heroku, netlify

I have a website which is made live through netlify. It opens up with a sign up page and leads to another static page. This static page is served through the 'action' method in form's submit button. Then we have a button which should lead to another static page, which should be reached similarly through an 'action' method. However this doesn't happen and shows me a 404 error.

It works on localhost but not on the live website made through netlify.

```
<div class="container" role="main">
    <div  class="center-block text-center">
    <form action="add.html" method="post">  <!-- /This add.html doesn't open up -->
        <button  class="btn btn-success">Add Event</button>
      </form>
    <form action="https://sayyam-event-assignment.herokuapp.com/myForm" method="post">
        <button  class="btn btn-success">List Events</button>
      </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is the heroku tag extraneous?

Comment: Yes, that works fine. There are multiple post requests in the website, and one even similar to this one. All of them work except this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Netlify bots might not be able to find the form — is the form hard coded, or are you generating it client-side with JavaScript?

Check out this section of their form-handling docs: https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/#javascript-rendered-forms

EDIT: On second look, I think you're just missing the `data-netlify="true"` attribute on the form tag.

Comment: This got it working, but I don't get it, the other form tags with post requests didn't have them either but they worked.

Comment: This form probably loaded before the Netlify bots scrubbed the page, but the other forms were after — you probably just got (un)lucky that the other ones worked.